ffmpeg libx265 x265-params will not enable frame-dup
I sometimes use libx265 to encode a video because it can do gray scale. I have obtained very good results with this:
ffmpeg -y -hide_banner -err_detect ignore_err -loglevel info -stats -benchmark -ec deblock 
-i "inpur.mp4" ^
 -pix_fmt gray12le -vsync vfr -mbd rd -c:a libopus ^
 -sws_flags +accurate_rnd -dst_range 1 -color_range 2 ^
 -c:v libx265 -crf 28 -preset medium -bufsize 64M -qmin 0 -qmax 68 -subq 8 -idct auto -flags +aic+mv4+qpel+loop+gray ^
 -x265-params "me=star:rd=5:rect=1:amp=1:hevc-aq=1:vbv-bufsize=12800:vbv-maxrate=1500:range=full:frame-dup=1" ^
 -movflags +faststart  "output.mp4"

I want to add the x265 option "frame-dup", but it appears to be impossible. I have tried several different builds of FFMPG including 7.0, I have read literally dozens and dozens of web sites, I have copied their  examples, I have read the x265 documentation pages and searched them, and I can't find anyone who has said this will work.
If I change the x265-params string to:
"me=star:rd=5:rect=1:amp=1:hevc-aq=1:vbv-bufsize=12800:vbv-maxrate=1500:range=full:frame-dup=1"

the program runs but I get:
x265 [info]: HEVC encoder version 3.5+117-b34fb2c77

x265 [info]: build info [Windows][GCC 13.2.0][64 bit] 12bit

x265 [info]: using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast LZCNT SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2

x265 [warning]: hevc-aq enabled, disabling other aq-modes

x265 [warning]: Frame-duplication require NAL HRD and VBV parameters. Disabling frame duplication

x265 [info]: Unknown profile, Level-4 (High tier)
x

I have done a large number of tests with various permutations of qualifiers. The x265 documentation does not say there is a "nal-hrd' parameter, but some web pages say there is. I've tried adding it, but it doesn't help. Sometimes the program runs with no error messages but still does not enable frame-dup. And sometimes I get an error message saying there is no 'nal-hd' parameter.
I've tried removing the hevc-aq parameter, but that doesn't help. I can post a dozen or more test results if anyone wants them, but I think it would be a waste of time.
Has anyone anywhere actually gotten ffmpeg and libx264 to use the frame-dup option, and if so could you please post the complete ffmpeg command that works? Does anyone know how to turn on NAL HRD? Is it a parameter, or is there a separate NAL parameter that isn't in the published documentation?
Or, can anyone point me to a webpage that definitively says this options is not available in any build of ffmpeg?
